# how to increment a url with zeros every specific interval "Javascript"?

Tags: javascript

I want to increment a url automatically using javascript and use it in Greasemonky on "Firefox"

ex:

```
www.google.com/id=1
www.google.com/id=01
www.google.com/id=001
www.google.com/id=0001
```

how can I achieve that using javascript???

here is what I wrote

---

```
var numberr = “2”;
var totall = “”;
var timeout = 12000;

setTimeout(function() {
    var numm = “0” + numberr;
    totall = “http://www.google.com/id=0” + numm;
    window.location.href = totall;
}, timeout);
```

---

but i doesn't increment the zeros as i expected,

can anybody help me?

I don't know what is the problem, maybe it is the Greasemonkey?? I don't know

### ---------------------------------------------------------------

OK, It seems to be a javascript unfixable problem, So I'll implement the logic in a Windows application using C#, BUT I neet to know how to access [[firefox]] url , and reload action through C# in a windows application, can anybody help?????

Comment: once you changed the location to an external html page, you won't be able to run your javascript code.

Comment: good eye Zed, didnt even see that, too busy looking at the construction of the url to see what we were doing with it!

Comment: looks like this is the problem, so what is the solution????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable values won't persist between page loads, thus resetting the counter each time. There is a solution, however!

```
GM_setValue(key, value);
GM_getValue(key[, defaultValue]);
```

http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/advanced/gm_getvalue.html

Alternatively, you can parse the current URL to determine your location within the loop. Try this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Incremental URL
// @include        http://www.google.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

var url = 'http://www.google.com/id=',
    start = '2',
    prepend = '0',
    limit = 10,
    timeout = 1000*12,

    regex = new RegExp('^' + url + '(' + prepend + '{0,' + (limit-1) + '})' + start + '$');
    matches = window.location.href.match(regex);


if(matches) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = url + prepend + matches[1] + start;
    }, timeout);
}
```

Comment: I tryed this code, but it didn't work at all, nothing happened,
BUT I want to try the [GM_setValue, GM_getValue] but how can I put them in my code?
i am not a javascript expert!

Comment: It's DONE, I tryed the GM_setValue and GM_getValue, it works,
thanks a lot

Comment: Andrew, for the userscript above, you'll need to go to http://www.google.com/id=2 to start the loop. I'm glad you got the GM_set/getValue working.

Answer (score 0):

What number are you coming up with?  it looks like you are always going to be adding one more 0 than your description indicates since you are automatically adding one 0 with

```
var numm = “0” + numberr;
totall = “http://www.google.com/id=0” + numm;
```

by the look of those lines, even if you start out with "2", your first request will be

```
www.google.com/id=002
```

edit: and another thing, you are going to need to assign numm to numberrr at the end of the function call.  Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
var numberr = “2”;
var totall = “”;
var timeout = 12000;

setTimeout(function() {
var numm = “0” + numberr;
totall = “http://www.google.com/id=” + numm;
window.location.href = totall;
numberr = numm;
}, timeout);
```

edit again: ya, what Zed says, once you change your page location everything will reset anyways.

Comment: I did the last line "numberr = numm;"
but nothing happened
I tryed that

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var numberr = “2”;
var totall = “”;
var timeout = 12000;
var numm;
setTimeout(function() {
    numm += “0”;
    totall = “http://www.google.com/id=0” + numm + numberr;
    window.location.href = totall;
}, timeout);
```

Comment: since numm is a local variable, its always going to be null when the function is called right?

Comment: ok its always going to be null, but I assign it at the beginning of the function "var numm = “0” + numberr;"
see, It isn't supposed to be null, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
var xcall = function()
{
    this.url = "http://www.google.com/id=";
    this.count = 0;
    this.numberr = '1';
    this.timeout = 12000;
};

xcall.prototype.ceros = function() {
    var ret = "";
    for(var x=0; x<this.count; x++){
        ret += "0";
    }
    this.count++;
    return ret;
};

xcall.prototype.sto = function() {
    var locat = this.url + this.ceros() + this.numberr;
    alert(locat);
    //window.location.href = this.url + this.ceros + this.numberr;
};

var calls = new xcall();

setTimeout("calls.sto()", calls.timeout);
setTimeout("calls.sto()", calls.timeout);
```

Comment: I don't understand this code, "javascript is not my language", but I used it with Greasemonkey, but it didn't work at all, I don't know why?

I'd appreciated if you try it on your browser "firefox" using greasemonkey